# Multilayer perceptron with sigmoid activation produces straight line on sin(2x) regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to approximate noisy data from the sin(2x) function using a multilayer perceptron:

```
# Get data
datasets = gen_datasets()
# Add noise
datasets["ysin_train"] = add_noise(datasets["ysin_train"])
datasets["ysin_test"] = add_noise(datasets["ysin_test"])
# Extract wanted data
patterns_train = datasets["x_train"]
targets_train = datasets["ysin_train"]
patterns_test = datasets["x_test"]
targets_test = datasets["ysin_test"]
# Reshape to fit model
patterns_train = patterns_train.reshape(62, 1)
targets_train = targets_train.reshape(62, 1)
patterns_test = patterns_test.reshape(62, 1)
targets_test = targets_test.reshape(62, 1)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 10000
batch_size = patterns_train.shape[0]
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 2
n_hidden_2 = 2
n_input = 1
n_classes = 1

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 2 neurons
    layer_1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1']))
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 2 neurons
    layer_2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2']))
    # Output fully connected layer
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Construct model
logits = multilayer_perceptron(X)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.absolute_difference(labels = Y, predictions = logits, reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.NONE))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training Cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):

        _ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: patterns_train,
                                          Y: targets_train})
        c = sess.run(loss_op, feed_dict={X: patterns_test,
                                         Y: targets_test})
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch: {0: 4} cost={1:9}".format(epoch+1, c))
    print("Optimization finished!")
    outputs = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={X: patterns_test})
    print("outputs: {0}".format(outputs.T))
    plt.plot(patterns_test, outputs, "r.", label="outputs")
    plt.plot(patterns_test, targets_test, "b.", label="targets")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

When I plot this at the end, I get a straight line, as if I have a linear network. Take a look at the plot:

[image]

This is a correct minimization of the error for a linear network. But I shouldn't have a linear betwork because I'm using the sigmoid function in my `multilayer_perceptron()` function! Why is my network behaving like this?

Comment: What classes do your targets represent?

Comment: They are continuous y values in y = sin(2x). There are no classes. They look weird because they have quite a lot of Gaussian noise added to them.

Comment: That's what I thought. So are you trying to do a regression task?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Your model seems a bit weird. The inputs (scalars!) seem to be the sampling points of your signal, i.e., a linear increasing function starting at 0. The logit of each input is thus always >= 0 and asymtotically increasing to 1. sigmoid(3) is already 0.95, meaning your gradients are very small and so are the weight updates. Hence, the network does not learn much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `stddev=1.0` in [`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal), which you use for weight & bias initialization, is *huge*. Try an explicit value of `stddev=0.01` for the weights; as for the biases, common practice is to initialize them to zero.

As an initial approach, I would also try a higher `learning_rate` of 0.01 (or maybe not - see answer in a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934338/non-linear-regression-why-isnt-the-model-learning/48947516#48947516))