# Does Gradient Boosting detect non-linear relationships?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data, gradient-descent, non-linear-regression

I wish to train some data using [the Gradient Boosting Regressor of Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn-ensemble-gradientboostingregressor).

My questions are:

1) Is the algorithm able to capture non-linear relationships? For example, in the case of y=x^2, y increases as x approaches negative infinity and positive infinity. What if the graph looks like y=sin(x)?

2) Is the algorithm able to detect interactions/relationships among the features? Specifically, should I add features that are the sums/differences of the raw features to the training set?

Comment: a downvote for...?

Comment: For the *extrapolation* part (i.e. predicting outside the training range), my answer here may be useful: [Is deep learning bad at fitting simple non linear functions outside training scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795142/is-deep-learning-bad-at-fitting-simple-non-linear-functions-outside-training-sco/53796253#53796253) (it is about neural nets, but the rationale is applicable to ML models in general).